# Splitting the workload between DSE Search and DSE Analytics Spark

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I have 2 types of use cases - search and analytics. I also have 2 distinct ways to categorize my primary key candidate fields.

1. Partition keys by high-cardinality fields, where number of distinct values is between 100,000 and 10,000,000 for example:

   - Customer_id
   - Employee_id
   - IP_address
   - MAC_address

The query by a row key here typically returns a handful of results. Secondary indexes and faucets are practical, because they are on low-cardinality fields - see the #2 below.

2. Partition keys by low-cardinality fields, where number of unique values is less than a 100, for example:

   - event_type - like "purchase" or "authenticated_OK"
   - platform - like 5 types of OS or 50 types of Aplications
   - metric_type - like CPU_utilization
   - protocol - like http or ftp
   - SNMP MIB name
   - country code, like us, ca, uk
   - state, like de, ny

A typical query by a row key returns millions of results, maybe for further analytics.
Secondary indexes are less practical here, because they are often on high-cardinality fields of the kind #1 above.

**My question:**:
is modeling the data like in #1 above more suitable to DSE Search; and 
data modeling like #2 above more suitable for DSE Analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The First Use Case, if properly data modeled and on an appropriately sized cluster will be fine querying cassandra without any additional indexing (no secondary indexes or need for solr aka DSE Search).

The Second Use Case, is quite hard to know with the information provided; however, it does sound like it could be a case where a proper data model and an appropriately sized cluster for cassandra plus secondary indexes on the low cardinality fields, may be a good fit.  However, its unclear exactly what your access patterns are with the information provided.

I suggest you read this which provides some great info on seconday indexes and solr with cassandra: [When to use Cassandra vs. Solr in DSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884598/when-to-use-cassandra-vs-solr-in-dse)